# Power shell | Extract user name out of computer name in Domain Controller

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

How can I extract the user name in my active directory when I only have the computer name.

Obviously, no relation whats or ever between the computer name and the user name in terms of naming.

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page. What have you tried so far, and what errors/issues have you faced? StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Ideally provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you trying to extract a user from AD, and you only know what computer they have logged on from?

Comment: Uh oh -- the downvoting police are in full effect!  One-liners shouldn't be considering part of the "code-writing" service -- he's not asking for a compiled app or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArcSet's answer is great (it's what I'd do) but for basic PowerShellers, I'd have pushed them towards the AD-cmdlets like (Mitchell did):

```
Get-ADUser -Property samaccountname
```

or even:

```
Get-ADObject -ldapfilter '(objectcategory=user)' -Property samaccountname
```

Comment: Get-ADObject -ldapfilter '(objectcategory=user)' -Property samaccountname is actually great, I need to add to this query the assigned computer name per each user name, is it possible?

Comment: Yes... what property do you want?  just the name?  the distinguishedname?  There are a whole host of attributes that could qualify.  samaccount name is basically the 'name' field with a '$' after it.  If that's the case, just change the property field to -Property samaccountname,name

Comment: need to add to Get-ADObject -ldapfilter '(objectcategory=user)' -Property samaccountname, the assigned computer name to each one of the users.

Comment: tried- Get-ADObject -ldapfilter '(objectcategory=user)' -Property samaccountname, name and sameacountname are actually the same, they both represent the user name, I want to represent the user name and the "computer name" related to it. Many thanks.

Comment: The username and computer name have no interrelated fields as far as Active Directory is concerned.  In order to associate those two things, you have a number of options:  create a script that writes the last logged on user to a field in AD (computer description, custom extended attribute, etc.), read the local machine for last logged on user (which can be determined a number of different ways), read all domain controller security logs for user authentications to find what user logged into what machine last, or hook the authentication APIs on the DCs to perform custom logging.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you all users from the domain the current computer is joined to:

```
(([adsisearcher]“objectcategory=user”).FindAll()).Properties.samaccountname
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. however, where should I run the script in terms of the domain controller?

Comment: Run from any computer on the domain using a user that access to the domain

Comment: Hi, I have used the above script. however, it only shoe the user names (notices that not all of them), without any relation to computer name.

Comment: I want to see a list of computer names in the DC (around 150) with the username that uses it

Answer (score 0):

I recommend utilizing this cmdlet: Get-ADComputer.  After getting the AD information associated with this you can pipe the data out and utilize filters to get the information you require.  The filter code is also specified within the documentation.

Documentation can be found here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617192.aspx

Hope this helps (I'm not 100% sure if this is what you are looking for... The more details in your question the better)!